# Is it possible to do a POST request and get data back in a non-Rest service?

Tags: web-services, http, jquery

I would like to know wether it is technically correct to do an ajax POST request to the server and expect data returned from the server?

I am doing NOT doing REST.

Comment: you can achieve all the functionality via ajax that you can do with normal post. If it works with normal post request . It will work with ajax :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the purpose of POST. You really need to be a bit more specific.